# should I use different nonces for multiple forms on same page?

Tags: security, wordpress

I am developing a plugin, where I am using bootstrap nav tabs function to display different forms on selecting menu . I want to use nonce function . Should I give seperate nonce function for every form or same nonce  for all the forms as they are on the same page. Pls guide.?

Comment: It depends. Not sure what you want to do. It depends if you want the forms to submit only once, or something similar. Maybe add code mate? People might answer it more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each form should have its own nonce, even those forms are on the same page.
If the form is present in admin pages then we should use check_admin_referer function to verify the nonce.

example:

```
<html>
  <div>
    <form id="form1"method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="something" value=""/>
    <?php wp_nonce_field('some_form','some_form_nonce');?>
    <input type ="hidden" name="form_name" value ="1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form id="form2"method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="someother" value=""/>
    <?php wp_nonce_field('some_other','some_other_nonce');?>
    <input type ="hidden" name="form_name" value ="2"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
  </div>
</html>
```

after that on processing page you should add the code like this

```
<?php

 if(!isset($_POST['form_name'])){

  if($_POST['form_name']==1){

     if ( ! empty( $_POST ) && check_admin_referer( 'some_form', 'some_form_nonce' ) ) {

   // process form1 data

   }else if($_POST['form_name']=2){


    if ( ! empty( $_POST ) && check_admin_referer( 'some_other', 'some_other_nonce' ) ) {

   // process form2 data

    }
  }
 ?>
```

This code I tried in my app and is working as I expected...